# Most recent votes

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, voting

In my "recent" page, https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/userid, it shows me the most recent responses, but not the most recent votes. For that, I need to go to the Reputation tab.

So, if I had a bunch of activity a few hours ago, and then I notice that my reputation has changed, I have to do two clicks to try to compare activity. The "Top 5 Posts" is sorted by time (rather than reputation), so it pretends to be recent votes, but it's really not.

Can we make Top 5 Votes be Recent Votes instead (or as well perhaps), and have Top 5 Votes sorted by reputation (so that it doesn't feel like it's Recent Votes) ?

I'm not sure if this should really be a bug or a feature-request. It's a mixture of the two.

Answer (score 1):

> The "Top 5 Posts" is sorted by time
>   (rather than reputation), so it
>   pretends to be recent votes, but it's
>   really not.

Isn't sorted by time, mean that the most 'recent' votes appear on the top?

I will note that it doesn't show distinctiveness between different votes on the same post, it just shows the latest time, and the total of rep earned on that post in the appropriate timerange.

Comment: My current "Top 5 Posts" list is: `54m 3/30. 3h 1/10. 3h acc/15. 3h 3/30. 4h 3/30`. So it seems to be `SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 5 ... ORDER BY Rep DESC) ORDER BY Time DESC;` And I would rather it was just the subquery.

Comment: OK, I got it.  I would think they could have a remembered preference for Rep order or Time order, but they've declined user preference sortings (so far) on other requests, like on the Users questions and answers page.